# Highcharts: Is there a way to highlight a series' corresponding y-axis onPointHover?

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, yaxis

I'm currently using multiple y-axis in my chart, as in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lsq2nzk/1/. In my use case it's quite rare that it's nice enough to be one line per y-axis, so I was wondering if there was a way to highlight the y-axis that corresponds to the series being hovered over.

So this works if you store the previously hovered over series' y-axis and rerender the chart, but the performance of this is pretty bad. I also tried editing the json in onPointHover, to no avail.

Using this onPointHover function:

```
function onPointHover(e) {
    e.target.color = 'red'
    e.target.series.yAxis.userOptions.labels.style.color = "red"
}
```

works to update the point color, but not the yAxis color, despite the actual json being updated in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve it by looping through `series.yAxis.ticks` and changing its CSS `fill` property. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
function highlightSeries(series, color) {
  for (var key in series.yAxis.ticks) {
    series.yAxis.ticks[key].label.css({
      fill: color
    });
  }

  series.yAxis.axisTitle.css({
    fill: color
  });
}

...
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          var point = this,
            series = point.series,
            highlightColor = 'red';

          if (point.graphic) {
            point.graphic.attr({
              fill: highlightColor
            });
          }

          series.chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
            if (s.isHighlighted) {
              highlightSeries(s, s.color);
              s.isHighlighted = false;
            }
          });

          highlightSeries(series, highlightColor);
          series.isHighlighted = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vs3y0wh5/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr